# Ban uses of error() method call with detekt

Tags: kotlin, static-analysis, detekt

I wish to ban the uses of `error()` method.

My goal is to Ban the use of Generic exception. I can use rule `TooGenericExceptionThrown` if the code throws the error explicitly. However, when folks use `error` method. Which is defined in standard kotlin library.

```
public inline fun error(message: Any): Nothing = throw IllegalStateException(message.toString())
```

It doesn't get caught by `TooGenericExceptionThrown`.

I tried enabling `ForbiddenMethodCall` as below

```
  ForbiddenMethodCall:
    active: true
    methods:
      - 'kotlin.io.print'
      - 'kotlin.io.println'
      - 'kotlin.error(kotlin.Any)'
      - 'error(kotlin.Any)'
      - 'error()'
      - 'error'
      - 'kotlin.error'
```

When I run `./gradlew detektMain`  in command line, while it catches the use of `print` and `println` it doesn't catch `error` method call.

Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from the maintainer
https://github.com/detekt/detekt/discussions/6485

`./gradlew clean detektMain detektTest` checks all files and solves the problem I was facing.